# How to find the rows where row end date and next row start date has gap>1 for same id

Tags: sql-server

```
partition key | source id | row start date | row end date | row is current | id
--------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------
20150130001   | 1         | 1900-01-01     | 2015-01-30   | 0              | 1
20150131001   | 1         | 2015-01-31     | 2015-01-31   | 0              | 1
20150201001   | 1         | 2015-02-01     | 2015-02-01   | 0              | 1
20150213001   | 1         | 2015-02-02     | 2015-02-11   | 0              | 1
20150223001   | 1         | 2015-02-14     | 2015-02-23   | 0              | 1
20150303001   | 1         | 2015-02-24     | 2015-02-25   | 0              | 1
99991231001   | 1         | 2015-03-04     | 9999-12-31   | 1              | 1
```

How do I find the rows where row end date and next row start date has gap>1 for same id?

Comment: With a self-join or subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125(v=sql.110).aspx) or [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256(v=sql.110).aspx) functions. You can find more examples [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html)

Change the Table name from Table1 to your tablename and you should get something close.

```
With tblDates as (
select *,
        LEAD( [row start date], 1) OVER(Order by [row start date]) as NextStartDate
from Table1 )

select * 
from tblDates
Where DATEDIFF(d, [row end date], NextStartDate) > 1
```

Comment: I think u understand what I need to do. can u please show me how is my query gonna be?

Comment: Try that as an example?

Answer (score 0):

With this type of question, I instantly think of EXISTS().  Assuming your date fields are of datetime datatype:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM MyTable t2
  WHERE t1.id=t2.id
  AND DATEDIFF(dd, t1.[Row End Date], t2.[Row Start Date]) BETWEEN 0 AND 1
)
```

Comment: We just need to check with the OP if he wants to select the last row or not (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36236/5).

Comment: Working but not giving the desired result.

Comment: I need to find  gaps b/w row end date and next row start date where gap>1

Comment: Seems to me that's what my code should do.   Do you have an example of a case where it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using SQL Server 2012+, then you could use CROSS APPLY:

```
select *
from Table1 A
cross apply (
     select min(rowstartdate) 
     from Table1 where rowstartdate > A.rowenddate
     where id = A.id
) B(Minimo)
where DateDiff(DAY, A.rowenddate, B.Minimo) > 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36236/3)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I found is:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, t.endDate, (SELECT MIN(ti.startDate) FROM yourTable ti WHERE ti.partitionKey > t.partitionKey)) > 1
```

This query simply says: All rows that have a difference between current row end date and lowest (first) start date from next partition keys in day is greater than one (day).